# java regex questions

Tags: java, regex

Given that I have a string of number, like "12354789556", I need to check that string whether has digits from 0 to 9 at least once.

Can anyone tell me whether i can express this in regex please?

Comment: Please update the question with your attempt.

Comment: Sorry if I ask, but why do you need regex at all costs? You could use contains() for each character to check. Not a one-liner, but you could declare a function that does it, and I don't think it could be possibile in other ways.

Comment: If what you need is to check that your string contains every digits at least once, you might want to rephrase your question since current answers seem to miss that point.

Comment: sorry for confusing, i just want to know whether i can do it in regex

Comment: Yes you can, and no it's not a good idea.

Comment: i see, thanks a lot

Comment: No need for a regex, use `s.chars().filter(i -> i >= '0' && i <= '9').distinct().count() == 10;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With lookaheads :

```
^(?=.*0)(?=.*1)(?=.*2)(?=.*3)(?=.*4)(?=.*5)(?=.*6)(?=.*7)(?=.*8)(?=.*9)
```

If you want to restrict the string to digits only in addition to making sure it contains every digit :

```
^(?=.*0)(?=.*1)(?=.*2)(?=.*3)(?=.*4)(?=.*5)(?=.*6)(?=.*7)(?=.*8)(?=.*9)\d+$
```

Note that a version without lookaheads would be technically possible, but would realistically have to be crafted by code as it would have to enumerate all possible orders between digits (`10!` = 3628800 enumerations).

Answer (score 4):

If your strings contains only digits for example  "123548955664789556" then try:

```
System.out.println(myString.chars().distinct().count() == 10);
```

if your string can also contain letters for example sth like "bbb1235489556fhjerfs64789556"

```
System.out.println(myString.replaceAll("[^\\d]", "").chars().distinct().count() == 10);
```

Comment: @Aaron I agree,that is right. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it in Java like this:

```java
boolean containsAll = true;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (!str.contains("" + i)) {
        containsAll = false;
    }
}
return containsAll;
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, but I don't think that is what the OP wants. He wants to check that ALL the digits from 0 to 9 are present.

Comment: @Andreaジーティーオー ooooh, right, that makes sense. I get it, I'll edit.

Comment: yes , i want to check all present

Comment: @AdrienBrunelat: PS: I'm not the downvoter! :)

Answer (score 0):

A non-regex way would be to loop through the String and return false if the  `indexOf` returns -1:

```
static boolean checkAll(String s, char[] allNums) {
    for (int i = 0; i < allNums.length; i++) {
        if (s.indexOf(allNums[i]) == -1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

[Example](https://ideone.com/XjP3Pt)